# graphviz(dot language) can i get nodes in horizontal line?

Tags: graphviz, dot

```
digraph G{
    rankdir=LR;
    size="12.34";
    node [shape="rectangle"]
    apple -> "ball"
    subgraph cluster_0 {
             rankdir=LR;
             node[style = filled];
             color = blue
    subgraph cluster_4{
             rankdir=LR;
             node[style=filled];
             fontsize=15;
             l[fontcolor=red] e[fontcolor=red] i[fontcolor=red] 
             g[fontcolor=red] k[fontcolor=red]
             color=orange
             }
     subgraph cluster_3 {
             rankdir=LR;
             node [style=filled];
             fontsize=15
             "wq"[fontcolor=red,fontsize=12] ". . . . " "wqnn"
             [fontcolor=red,fontsize=12];
             label = "zebra";
             color=orange
             }
     subgraph cluster_2 {
             rankdir=LR;
             node [style=filled];
             fontsize=15
             struct3 [shape=record,fontsize=12, fontcolor=red, label="
             {{d1}|{ a | b | c }}"];
             struct4 [shape=record,fontsize=12, fontcolor=red, label="
             {{d2}|{ a | b | c }}"];
             struct5 [shape=record,fontsize=12, fontcolor=red, label="
             {{d3}|{ a | b }}"];
             struct6 [shape=record,fontsize=12, fontcolor=red, label="
             {{d4}|{ a }}"];
             ". . . . . ."
             struct7 [shape=record,fontsize=12, fontcolor=red, label="
             {{dn}|{a }}"];
             label = "tiger";
             color=orange
            }
   subgraph cluster_1{
            node[ style = filled];
            struct1 [shape=record, 
            rankdir=LR,fontsize=12,fontcolor=red, label="{{n}|{ x| y| 
            z }}"];
            ". . . . .  ."
            struct2 [shape=record, 
            rankdir=LR,fontsize=12,fontcolor=red, label="{{m}|{ x | y 
            | z }}"];
            label = "lion";
            fontsize=15
            color = orange
            }
           edge[color="violet"]
           "cat" -> "wq"
           "cat" -> "struct3"
           "cat" -> "struct1"
           "cat" -> "l"
        }
      "ball" -> "cat"[label="abc"];
}
```

I am a beginner(dot language and graphviz).I wrote code like this. but I want d1 d2 d3 d4 boxes in horizontal line. Please help me

[image: image.dot].

How I getting those boxes has horizontal. what can I do for this?. How can get those nodes as horizontal? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?  I made invisible links to enforce the left-to-right ordering. Combined with your `rankdir` setting, this makes them go left to right.

```
digraph G{
    rankdir=LR;
    size="12.34";
    node [shape="rectangle"]
compound=true;


    subgraph cluster_0 {
             rankdir=LR;
             node[style = filled];
             color = blue


    subgraph cluster_4{
             rankdir=LR;
             node[style=filled];
             fontsize=15;
             l[fontcolor=red] e[fontcolor=red] i[fontcolor=red] 
             g[fontcolor=red] k[fontcolor=red]
             color=orange

    l -> e -> i -> g -> k [style=invis];

             }



     subgraph cluster_3 {
             rankdir=LR;
             node [style=filled];
             fontsize=15
             "wq"[fontcolor=red,fontsize=12] ". . . . " "wqnn"
             [fontcolor=red,fontsize=12];
             label = "zebra";
             color=orange


    dummy3 [label = "" style=invis]
    dummy4 [label = "" style=invis]
    wqnn -> dummy3 -> dummy4 [style=invis]
    wq -> ". . . . " -> "wqnn" [style=invis];
             }


     subgraph cluster_2 {
             rankdir=LR;
             node [style=filled];
             fontsize=15
             struct3 [shape=record,fontsize=12, fontcolor=red, label="
             {{d1}|{ a | b | c }}"];
             struct4 [shape=record,fontsize=12, fontcolor=red, label="
             {{d2}|{ a | b | c }}"];
             struct5 [shape=record,fontsize=12, fontcolor=red, label="
             {{d3}|{ a | b }}"];
             struct6 [shape=record,fontsize=12, fontcolor=red, label="
             {{d4}|{ a }}"];

     struct3 -> struct4 -> struct5 -> struct6 -> struct7 [style=invis];

             struct7 [shape=record,fontsize=12, fontcolor=red, label="
             {{dn}|{a }}"];
             label = "tiger";
             color=orange
            }

   subgraph cluster_1{
            node[ style = filled];
            struct1 [shape=record, 
            rankdir=LR,fontsize=12,fontcolor=red, label="{{n}|{ x| y| 
            z }}"];
            ". . . . .  ."
            struct2 [shape=record, 
            rankdir=LR,fontsize=12,fontcolor=red, label="{{m}|{ x | y 
            | z }}"];
            label = "lion";
            fontsize=15
            color = orange

    dummy1 [label = "" style=invis]
    dummy2 [label = "" style=invis]
    struct2 -> dummy1 -> dummy2 [style=invis]
    struct1 -> ". . . . .  ." -> struct2  [stle=invis];
            }


           edge[color="violet"]
           "cat" -> "wq" [lhead=cluster_3 ]
           "cat" -> "struct3" [lhead=cluster_2 ]
           "cat" -> "struct1" [lhead=cluster_1 ]
           "cat" -> "l" [lhead=cluster_4  ]

        }

      "ball" -> "cat"[label="abc"];
       apple -> "ball"

}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for helping me. This way I need. And also for zebra, lion(sub graph clusters) and last box(node). Can you please help me to move forward. Thanks a lot

Comment: And arrows(edges) will be outside of the box(edges will touch just yellow boxes) should not go in side of the cluster. Can you please consider above raw image for this. Thank You.

Comment: The arrows going from the cat are now connecting to one particular node in each subgraph cluster. Instead, the arrow should connect to the outside box itself. (please consider the image which I posted). Thanks

Comment: The four cluster boxes are not aligned good and that looks odd. How can I write the code for good alignment(four cluster boxes)?.  so, please consider me an absolute beginner. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AnushaKonduru Here you go, I think it's complete now.  I hope this helps you.  [Please also read this, thanks](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: only apple and ball nodes(boxes) are outside of the entire box. Can you please help for this.

Comment: And I want each lion, tiger, and zebra boxes length should be equal.

Comment: @AnushaKonduru With some extra hidden dummy nodes to push the yellow borders to the right and proper nesting of the main cluster, I think this  meets all your requirements.  Since I was the only one to respond to your call for help, please consider [reading this note on etiquette](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and Accept my answer, thank you.